# Scala combination function issue

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a input file like this:

```
The Works of Shakespeare, by William Shakespeare 
Language: English
```

and I want to use `flatMap` with the `combinations` method to get the K-V pairs per line.

This is what I do:

```
var pairs = input.flatMap{line => 
  line.split("[\\s*$&#/\"'\\,.:;?!\\[\\(){}<>~\\-_]+")
    .filter(_.matches("[A-Za-z]+"))
    .combinations(2)
    .toSeq
    .map{ case array => array(0) -> array(1)}
}
```

I got 17 pairs after this, but missed 2 of them: `(by,shakespeare)` and `(william,shakespeare)`. I think there might be something wrong with the last word of the first sentence, but I don't know how to solve it, can anyone tell me?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please avoid posting images and instead post your code as text and format it by selecting the code and pressing Ctrl + K. You can also read [ask] for more information. Remember to provide a [mcve]

Comment: With `combinations` you will get either `(by,shakespeare)` or `(shakespeare,by)`, not both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `combinations` method will not give duplicates even if the values are in the opposite order. So the values you are missing already appear in the solution in the other order.

This code will create all ordered pairs of words in the text.

```
  for {
    line <- input
    t <- line.split("""\W+""").tails if t.length > 1
    a = t.head
    b <- t.tail
  } yield a -> b
```

Here is the description of the `tails` method:

> Iterates over the tails of this traversable collection. The first value will be this traversable collection and the final one will be an empty traversable collection, with the intervening values the results of successive applications of tail.